# Non-zero values in text field

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5, xcode6

I am very new to iPhone & iPad development.

I have a text field. What is the procedure to check that the textfield value is a non zero value?

I've already written the logic to check with `null` value and empty string, but could not get the logic with non zero value checking of a textfield content.

EX:

```
if (Salerttxt.text  != (id)[NSNull null] && Salerttxt.text.length > 0 && ![Salerttxt.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![Salerttxt.text isEqualToString: @"0"])
```

This above only checks the empty string.  If the user enters the value as "0" , then its working. But in case use enter more times "0" value. eg. 00, 000, 000......
it accepts and my logic fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Salerttxt.text != (id)[NSNull null] && Salerttxt.text.length > 0 && ![Salerttxt.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![Salerttxt.text intValue] == 0)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([Salerttxt.text isEqualToString @"0"] || Salerttxt.text.length == 0)
{
   //this check for null value or if string is empty
}

else
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Salerttxt.text && ![Salerttxt.text isEqualToString:@""] && [Salerttxt.text intValue] != 0)
```

Comment: You could add some more detail to your answer. (:

Answer (score 0):

Convert the text to an integer and test that, and that will validate `0`, `00`, etc.

```
if ([Salerttxt.text length] > 0 && [Salerttxt.text intValue] > 0) {
    ...
}
```